# Reshape three matrices into one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Suppose `test = np.array(5*[np.eye(5), 10*np.eye(5), 15*np.eye(5)])`. I have three matrices inside an array with shape `(3, 5, 5)`. In general, how can I reshape `test` to make the three matrices into one? In that specific example, I would like the shape to be `(15, 5)`. I want a general way of doing it without using some reeally specific as `np.reshape(test, (15,5))`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be more precise when saying "to make the three matrices into one". What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: `test` as described is one `numpy` array.  You started with 3 2d arrays and end up with one 3d one.

Comment: I guess ```test.reshape(-1,test.shape[2])``` is as short and non specific as one can get.

Comment: What's wrong with the specific shape?  It's not hard to get the `15` from the `3,5`. 
 `np.reshape( test, (test.shape[0]*test.shape[1], test.shape[2]))`.  The answers suggest the `-1` shortcut, but even without that the reshape is easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -1 in reshape that implicitly calculates the required dimension shape:

```
test = test.reshape(-1, test.shape[-1])
```